# How important is to show Extracurricular or Leadership skills in SOP apart from academic background and research interests?

Tags: phd, united-states, statement-of-purpose

I have an 83-word small paragraph in my SOP (computer science, PhD) mentioning that I am the honorary moderator of a computer club and how I organize events and motivate students to participate in competitions. Also, a team from this club became the winner of the international blockchain olympiad. Now, is this paragraph in any way important to the admissions committee? Due to the word limit in my SOP, I have decided to remove the whole paragraph. Do you think removing the paragraph is a good or bad idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace that with more important and relevant information then it is a good idea to remove it. It has little to do with your goals and purpose of wanting doctoral study or your career goals. Those latter points are the purpose of the Statement of *Purpose*.

If your academic goals involve blockchain advances then you might include a phrase about that accomplishment, but probably not otherwise.

Put that information in your CV, since they detail past accomplishments. Make the SoP forward looking: goals and purpose. Only use the past to help set a basis for those goals.